# Elements of Array are getting change after .push, why?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have a simple code that, from a range in spreadsheet is taking only elements that ends in a month (I use those data to create timeline in apps-script)

I was able  to do everything but at the last moment of the code when I want to push the result to the new final array it is getting weird...

so, `Logger.log(newAr[i])` prints out all elements that I want in my new array
`[HCQ, NC32313, Tue Dec 22 08:25:00 GMT-05:00 2020, Tue Dec 22 08:26:00 GMT-05:00 2020]`

then I have this `final.push(i);` which should insert all elements to new array and everything should be ok I guess..

but then `Logger.log(final);` gives me this output:
`[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0......]`
which is nothing like the element above....

Anyone knows why is this happening and how can I fixed it?
Below my code:

```
function timelineData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KzaKe9ShAZZAlK3CQC-UmrKzZXghNKAAx_pDHFX3YLI/edit#gid=0');
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Array");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow()-1, 4).getDisplayValues()
  const newAr = srcValues.map(r=>[r[0],r[1], new Date(r[2]), new Date(r[3])]);
  
  
 var final = [];
  
     const today = new Date();
     const thirtyDays = today.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
     const monthAfter = new Date(thirtyDays);
     

     for(var i = 0; i < newAr.length; i++){
       if(newAr[i][3] <= monthAfter){
         Logger.log(newAr[i]);
        final.push(i);
          
       }
     }


Logger.log(final);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, at `final.push(i);`, the index is put to the array. I think that this is the reason of your issue. When you want to put the value to the array, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
final.push(i);
```

#### To:

```
final.push(newAr[i]);
```